# advanced mode for errors displaying during development right in browser (Ruby-on-Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

it would be nice to see some additional info about exceptions just in browser. not only exception itself with few lines of code and not necessary (for me during development) stack traces but, for example, sql and, maybe, some more info - like exact place of problem in looong line of code (it is possible, i guess). it would be very helpful to see exact objects (truncated if it would be long) instead of `Array:0x00000103e26ea0` in

```
undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x00000103e26ea0>
```

even additional info from log would be nice to see right in browser without switching to log every time

any tricks (gems, monkey-patches) on this?

in other words: what do you use to pleasurify (is this word exists?:))  development process?

thanx in advance

Comment: The development log output includes most if not all of what you're asking for. Are you reading that when you encounter errors?

Comment: my one doesn't show:

- exact place of error over string (sometimes i have to split it for several strings to see where the problem is)

- "exact" objects like "['one', 'two', 'three']" instead of "abstract" objects like #<Array:0x00000103e26ea0>

- ...

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing that does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the development log (which includes your SQL errors) you might take a look at [Hammertime](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/01/18/hammertime/) or [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), both of which are good debuggers that let you inspect your code more carefully around an exception.

Comment: i mean not SQL errors but even correct SQL if error is somewhere else

Comment: In particular, the pry-exception_explorer plugin for Pry: https://github.com/pry/pry-exception_explorer